# What does it mean "Could not find a part of the path"?

Tags: powershell

Is there a limit to the size of the path the `get-childitem` and `select-string` can handle? If yes what is the alternative?

When I run the following command on the path:

```
PS E:\KINGSTON backup5\03 Learning\Softwares\Mathematica\Mathematica 12\Mathematica Directories Backup2\C,Users,atfai,AppData,Roaming,Mathematica\Paclets\Repository\SystemDocsUpdate1-12.0.0\Documentation\English\Workflows> get-childitem -recurse -filter "*.nb" -file | select-string -pattern ".*ProcessObject.*" -casesensitive
```

I get the following error

> select-string : The file E:\KINGSTON backup5\03
>   Learning\Softwares\Mathematica\Mathematica 12\Mathematica Directories
>   Backup2\C,Users,atfai,AppData,Roaming,Mathematica\Paclets\Repository\SystemDocsUpdate1-12.0.0\Documentation\English\Workflows\ChangeTheStyleOfPointsInA2DScatterPlot.nb
>   cannot be read: Could not find a part of the path 'E:\KINGSTON
>   backup5\03 Learning\Softwares\Mathematica\Mathematica 12\Mathematica
>   Directories
>   Backup2\C,Users,atfai,AppData,Roaming,Mathematica\Paclets\Repository\SystemDocsUpdate1-12.0.0\Documentation\English\Workflows\ChangeTheStyleOfPointsInA2DScatterPlot.nb'.
>   At line:1 char:47
>   + ... nb" -file | select-string -pattern ".*ProcessObject.*" -casesensitive ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-String], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProcessingFile,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand

Moreover if I run the same command on the following path:

```
PS E:\Computer Backup\Downloads - Current\Windows 10 Optimization\SoftwareDistribution.old3\Download\736aed4d238d4999f5ea5b04589077ed\Package_for_RollupFix~~amd64~~17134.677.1.6\x86_wcf-system.servicemodel_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.17134.254_none_d5ff175e12d127c0> get-childitem -recurse -filter "*.nb" -file | select-string -pattern ".*ProcessObject.*" -casesensitive
```

I get the error this time from `get-childitem`

> get-childitem : Could not find a part of the path 'E:\Computer
>   Backup\Downloads - Current\Windows 10
>   Optimization\SoftwareDistribution.old3\Download\736aed4d238d4999f5ea5b
>   04589077ed\Package_for_RollupFix~~amd64~~17134.677.1.6\x86_wcf-system.servicemodel_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.17134.254_none_d5ff175e12d127c0'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + get-childitem -recurse -filter "*.nb" -file | select-string -pattern  ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (E:\Computer Bac...5ff175e12d127c0:String) [Get-ChildItem],
>   DirectoryNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

What does it mean "Could not find a part of the path"? The drive E has NTFS file system which is supported by Windows so its powershell commands should be able to handle it? What is going on here?

BTW I can access both paths from the Windows explorer and open the files in the notepad. So the paths exist and files are clearly not corrupt or inaccessible.

Comment: why are you NOT using quotes with paths that have embedded spaces?

Comment: Actually, the real question should be, why do you include `PS E:\Computer Backup\Downloads - Current\Windows 10 Optimization\SoftwareDistribution.old3\Download\736aed4d238d4999f5ea5b04589077ed\Package_for_RollupFix~~amd64~~17134.677.1.6\x86_wcf-system.servicemodel_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.17134.254_none_d5ff175e12d127c0>` in your code like this? Makes it really difficult to understand what the actual command is you are running.

Comment: Whenever I had issues with locations (which certainly existed), using the `-LiteralPath` parameter helped.

Comment: @FatalBulletHit can you tell me how to add the `-LiteralPath` parameter since path in this case is found by one command and piped into the other?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'E:\Computer Backup\Downloads - Current\Windows 10 Optimization\SoftwareDistribution.old3\Download\736aed4d238d4999f5ea5b04589077ed\Package_for_RollupFix~~amd64~~17134.677.1.6\x86_wcf-system.servicemodel_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.17134.254_none_d5ff175e12d127c0'`

Comment: @FatalBulletHit tried: `get-childitem -literalpath "E:\Computer Backup\Downloads - Current\Windows 10 Optimization\SoftwareDistribution.old3\Download\736aed4d238d4999f5ea5b04589077ed\Package_for_RollupFix~~amd64~~17134.677.1.6\x86_wcf-system.servicemodel_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.17134.254_none_d5ff175e12d127c0" -recurse -filter "*.nb" -file | select-string -pattern "ProcessObject" -casesensitive` but still getting the same error.

Comment: I don't see where this would cause an error if the path exists. Double check the path maybe? Can you use `cd` to the location?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i did and hence the `PS E:\Computer Backup\Downloads - Current\Windows 10 Optimization\SoftwareDistribution.old3\Download\736aed4d238d4999f5ea5b04589077ed\Package_for_RollupFix~~amd64~~17134.677.1.6\x86_wcf-system.servicemodel_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.17134.254_none_d5ff175e12d127c0>` was included since I was working from exactly this directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201350/discussion-between-fatalbullethit-and-user13892).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that long paths aren't enabled on your OS, so there is a limit of 260 characters.

Depending on the version of windows you are running, this can be fixed by enabling the group policy `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > NTFS > Enable NTFS long paths`.

If you don't have that option, changing the value of the registry key `LongPathsEnabled` at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` from `0` to `1` does the job as well.

Comment: +1 for the diagnosis. Do you know if the registry option still works if the path is on a server? e.g. do both server and client need to have long path enabled? (assume both are Windows)

Comment: @mattwilkie No idea I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use the registry or group policy fix of the other answer you may be able to work around this by using the prefix `\\?\E:\folder1\...`

> To specify an extended-length path, use the "\?" prefix. For example, "\?\D:\very long path".
> [...]
> The "\?" prefix can also be used with paths constructed according to
> the universal naming convention (UNC). To specify such a path using
> UNC, use the "\?\UNC" prefix. For example, "\?\UNC\server\share",
> where "server" is the name of the computer and "share" is the name of
> the shared folder.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd

Comment: It works. 
dir -Recurse \\?\UNC\MyTopDir

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what it says, at the exact moment of writing a file, the directory doesn't exist.

Bumped into this with a C# .NET 8 async file copying program, where the IO is flooded with async file copying commands.  Before copying each file, the app checked if it firstly needed to create the new destination sub folder asynchronously.

```
    // Both async functions are extension method versions of their respective base functions.
    ioTasks.Add(fileInfo.Directory.CreateSafelyAsync());  
    ioTasks.Add(fileInfo.CopyToSafelyAsync(targetFileInfo));
...
    await Task.WhenAll(ioTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);    // Only do a batch at a time.
    await Task.Delay(50);
```

While it did knock out the first few files and folders worth, there are no guarantees that async calls are executed in the intended order or in a timely manner. And from my observation particularly when the IO is overloaded, somehow the new sub folder wasn't available in time, for the first file to be copied into it.

Now I could do a retry at this point but exceptions are VERY performance heavy, and it's best to avoid them whenever possible.  For instance it's way cheaper and easier to test a filename string for invalid characters, than it is to deal with it as an exception.

Instead what did, seeing as I had already loaded a generic list with all the filenames, was to firstly do the directory creation in it's own loop, before the file copying loop.

```
    HashSet<DirectoryInfo> uniqueDirectoryInfos = new HashSet<DirectoryInfo>(100);
    for (var idx = 0; idx < fileInfos.Count; idx++)
    {
        uniqueDirectoryInfos.Add(fileInfos[idx].Directory);
    }

    foreach (var uniqueDirectoryInfo in uniqueDirectoryInfos)
    {
        await uniqueDirectoryInfo.CreateSafelyAsync(new IoRetryStrategy());
    }
```

Even though I'm looping through `fileInfos`, my filename list, twice, this first loop has no IO calls, so is done entirely in memory and exceedingly fast.  It then allows the file copying process to just get on with the job without waiting around for anything.

So far I've tested this on 270,000 files and this simple change cut the overall time in half.  I have clients with up to 3 billion files so this needs to be rock solid and as fast a possible.